# TweetInvi API C#

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, streaming, tweetinvi

I'm using TweetInvi Streaming API to watch my twitter timeline and send me a mail everytime someone tweet with the word "AREA2017";

This is where i'am so far:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("consumerkey", "consumersecret", "accesstoken", "accesstokensecret");
var user = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser();

var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();

stream.AddTrack("AREA2017");

stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, arguments) =>
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("somemail@gmail.com", "mygmailpassword");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(new MailMessage("somemail2@gmail.com", "somemail2@gmail.com", "Hi !", "body"));
    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Tweet.Text);
};

stream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
```

So, i don't have much idea why it's not working, i follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-lJm-bqyI0
+

I check to send me a mail with my code and it's working well, the api just don't find any tweet containing "AREA2017".

Comment: I have this same issue working with .netcore. Do you have a solution now? @another-gitssoldier

Comment: No i'm sorry, i've droped the project to move to another (School project) cause i didn't discover why it doesn't find my tweet...
If you ever find a solution, come and tell me what it was, i'm curious :)

Comment: Alright. Thanks